# What will be the acceleration of an object $A$ when its released by another object $B$ moving with an upward acceleration $a$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

What will be the acceleration of an object $A$ when its released by another object $B$ moving with an upward acceleration $a$? Will the acceleration of the object $A$ be more than the acceleration due to gravity or less than it?
Will the net acceleration reduce or increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be exactly the acceleration due to gravity, because no other force is acting on it.

**Edit answering comment:**

You're thinking about velocity. Acceleration isn't something an object has. Objects accelerate because there's an external force acting on them. When B is towing A, it exerts a force on A which causes A to accelerate. When B lets go, that external force disappears, so the only acceleration A will now experience is gravitational acceleration.

Consider B is towing A up with an acceleration of $5~m/s^2$ for $10~s$, after which it lets go. Even after it lets go, the body still has an upwards velocity, so it will continue moving upwards (see graphs). However, nothing is pushing it upwards, but gravity continues to pull it down, so after some time, the object stops moving upwards and starts moving downwards. At this point, its velocity is zero (and then becomes negative), but it's acceleration has been negative, i.e. downwards for quite some time now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: :what about the upward acceleration 'a' acting on it?

Comment: @Flare'D, see my edit.

Comment: do you mean that the upward acceleration acts on the object only upto the point when its released ? and then it just gets neglected ?

Comment: Yes. Beyond that point, gravity is the only thing that is changing its velocity, so it's acceleration is $g$

Comment: thanks I think I got the point - objects on free fall only experience gravity no matter what the acceleration is with which it moves up ?

Comment: @Flare'D, yes. I've added some graphs to help you understand better.